# google play console: cannot download apk from artifact library

Tags: google-play

I'm not able to download my old APK's - there is no such option in artifact library:
[image: Artifact library screenshot]
 Anyone has idea why??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only see the download link if you have the "Manage production releases" and "Manage alpha and beta releases" in your user permissions.

[Manage permissions docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en-GB)

Are you the account owner?